# is FSID really needed for NFS export?

Tags: nfsv4

reference:

- [implications of using NFSv4 fsid=0 and exporting the NFS root to entire LAN (or not)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427597/implications-of-using-nfsv4-fsid-0-and-)
  exporting-the-nfs-root-to-entire-lan-or
- https://earlruby.org/2022/01/setting-up-nfs-fsid-for-multiple-networks/

  - *When I’m setting up NFS servers I **like** to assign each exported volume with a unique FSID...*
  - *If you use a different FSID for one of these entries, or if you declare the FSID for one subnet and not the other, your NFS server will slowly and mysteriously grind to a halt, sometimes over hours and sometimes over days.*

    - seems like explicitly using `fsid` in `/etc/exports` can cause problems?

> *from the earlruby link above:*
>
> If you don’t use FSID, there is a chance that when you reboot your NFS server the way that the server identifies the volume will change between reboots, and your NFS clients will hang with “stale file handle” errors. I say “a chance” because it depends on how your server stores volumes, what version of NFS it’s running, and if it’s a fault tolerant / high availability server, how that HA ability was implemented. Using a unique FSID ensures that the volume that the server presents is always identified the same way, and it makes it easier for NFS clients to reconnect and resume operations after an NFS server gets rebooted.

- https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports

In reading the man page and other resources, I do not understand the real need for doing an explicit `fsid=<some number>` in `/etc/exports`.  Can someone explain to me when and why you would do such a thing, in RHEL 8.9 or later with NFS vers=4.2, especially when I personally have never explicitly done used `fsid=` and have never had a problem.

When one explicitly states `fsid=<some number>` in `/etc/exports`, how is that identifier chosen?  How do you ensure it is unique?

If I am only nfs exporting folders that are local mounts such as `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1` and I mount them via UUID in my `/etc/fstab` and they are XFS file systems does that basically guarantee that I do not have to use `fsid=` in `/etc/exports`?  What if any of those local mounted filesystems are NTFS-3g?

What file systems are problematic per the description of the nfs man page?  *Not all filesystems are not stored on devices*... what does this mean*?

Answer (score 0):

The description included is pretty clear I think.

fsid is an optional feature.  Without it, other factors help identify a filesystem.  However (as stated), these "other factors" are unstable and could change.  Using fsid to identify the filesystem would increase reliability, stability across reboots, and version compatibility.

As with most user specified optional parameters, fsid is chosen by you, and you determine how to choose it.  Preferably, you make it unique between exported filesystems somehow.

fsid is a relatively new option (new in NFSv4 I think), so it may trigger bugs.  It may not be necessary for simple configurations and current versions.  It hasn't been necessary for years, and likely will remain optional for most configurations.

But if you have a problem with aliased or stale nfs mounts after a reboot or upgrades, you may have discovered it is necessary...

Comment: I guess I am wanting to know what `other factors`  actually are to know when I need to use `fsid=`.  Otherwise the explanation so far in my opinion is lacking it's just a surface explanation... the claim is use for reliability/stability however I've never used it and **never** had a reliability/stability problem.

Comment: *...because it depends on how your server stores volumes, what version of NFS it’s running...*  So in what linux setup that store volumes how is the problem?  Because it certainly isn't when it is an XFS or EXT4 local disk mount that is nfs exported.  And what version of NFS ?  There's no technical detail to be found of of these superficial claims.

Comment: @ron ya, can't argue that point.  And I also am leaving it blank.  Until something breaks or the documentation changes.